# How to query Wikidata using labels in a specific language + other filtering criteria?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My goal is to query Wikidata and obtain a list of living persons whose label contains a specific string.

For instance, with this code I searched for Silvio Berlusconi and obtained as a result Pier Silvio Berlusconi, because Silvio is dead and Pier Silvio is still leaving.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q5.
      MINUS {
        ?item p:P570 ?statement_1.
        ?statement_1 psv:P570 ?statementValue_1.
        ?statementValue_1 wikibase:timeValue ?P570_1.
      }
      ?item p:P735 ?statement2.
      ?statement2 (ps:P735/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q539504.
      ?item p:P734 ?statement3.
      ?statement3 (ps:P734/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q24073854.
    }
    LIMIT 10
  }
}
```

The result is fine, but the problem is that I used separate properties for the person's name (P735 = given name, P734 = family name) and set each of them equal to specific values (Q539504 = Silvio, Q24073854 = Berlusconi). I need to search for just a string (e.g. "Silvio Berlusconi) withing the items' labels, without separating the string into multiple values (given name = Silvio, family name = Berlusconi).

Comment: either you use a) the string values in the `rdfs:label` of each node (given name and family name)) and hope that the strings match exactly, or b) you use the Wikidata entity search via SPARQL which does make use of a fulltext-index backed by ElasticSearch, thus, being more efficient. Reagrding the language, those have to be a) attached to the literal, e.g. `"Silvio"@en` or for b) you can configure the language in the entity search.